# Extending class with protocol VS implementing the protocol inside the class

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, delegates, protocols

I am in a process to learn Swift 3, and its unique paradigm structure in respect to Objective-C and I stumbled upon a design pattern which I am not sure what to make out. Let me lay out the question directly.

Previously in Objective-C, we can implement a protocol/ delegate in the class itself. I see there is a Swift equivalent that is very much similar to this.

Example:

```
class myClass : UIViewController , UITextFieldDelegate {
     // somewhere inside the class we implement the delegate of 
     // UITextfieldDelegate, something like this

       func doSomething(){
           theTextField.delegate = self
       }

       func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
          // works just fine
       }

}
```

Now this is exactly how we did it in Objective-C. But now I am getting another way to implement protocol/delegate in classes.

```
  class MyClass : UIViewController , UITextFieldDelegate {

   func doSomething(){
       theTextField.delegate = self
   }

 }

 extension MyClass : UITextFieldDelegate{
      func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
           //Even this works fine
     }
 }
```

Now I am a bit puzzled. Is this also another way to implement delegation pattern, or there is much more to this? Is this just a design paradigm or does it has some other purpose too?

Comment: This is a decent related article: https://www.natashatherobot.com/using-swift-extensions/

Comment: It is Swift convention to name your classes starting with a capital letter. BTW you are extending `EQHomeViewController`
 instead of `MyClass`

Comment: @LeoDabus My bad, please ignore the typos. I have edited them

Answer (score 0):

The objective answer is:

There is no difference between the two.

The subjective answer is:

It depends on your code organization style. Some people consider "cleaner" to conform to protocols by using extensions since it isolates the code that actually belongs to the conformance logic.

So for example, a single class might have to implement the delegate and datasource (for UITableViews) but might also conform to other custom classes, and by using extensions you can CLEARLY see what code is used to conform to what protocol.

This wasn't much of an issue in Objective-C since you could simply use #PRAGMA Mark - and you could have your code cleanly organized. Since there is no such a thing in Swift some people use extensions to split their code. (As seen in Natasha's article linked to you in the comments).

However, it's often considered good practice to implement protocol conformance through extensions. (Since there is a clear separation from the rest of the logic)

---

Additionally, there's one extra benefit about using protocols, and its that you can actually add conformance to classes you wouldn't normally have access to (those not built by you).

I recommend the swift documentation, since it clearly explains this.

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Extensions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH24-ID151

Another special case that is quite interesting is extending a protocol itself, which is used to provide "default" behavior to that protocol so that you don't have to implement it in every class that you want to make conformant to it.